# How to invoke another serializer from a custom Gson JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, jsonserializer

I have my custom class `User`:

```
class User {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public Address address;
    public Timestamp created;
}
```

I'm now creating a custom JsonSerializer for User.class:

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(User src, Type typeOfSrc,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("name", src.name);
    obj.addProperty("id", src.id);
    obj.addProperty("address", src.address.id);

    // Want to invoke another JsonSerializer (TimestampAdapter) for Timestamp   
    obj.add("created", ???);
    return obj;
}
```

But I already have a `TimestampAdapter` that I use for `Timestamp.class`. How can I invoke this `JsonSerializer` to be used on the "created"-field in `User.class`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
obj.add("created", context.serialize(src.created));
```

If your `TimestampAdapter` is registered with Gson for the `Timestamp` class, the `JsonSerializationContext` should automatically use it to serialize the object and return a `JsonElement`.