# Gson : StackOverflowError

Tags: java, json, gson, stack-overflow

The below codes causing `StackOverflowError`. purpose of the code is to create a json string from java class.

```
for (ControlTransaction crt : ctrList) {
                crt= new ControlTransaction();// for test, Still issue
                final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                ControlTransaction.class,
                  new ControlTransactionSerializer()).create();
                String jsonControlTransactionString = gson.toJson(crt);
                strList.add(jsonControlTransactionString);

            }
```

My class looks like

```
public class ControlTransaction implements IsSerializable, Serializable ,IsBean{
    private long id;
    private String value; // H
    private String lastValue; // H
    private FormTransaction formTransaction;
    private List<FormTransaction> gridRows;
    private ControlTransaction referenceGridTransaction;
    private RowTransaction fkRowTransaction;
    private ReportTransaction reportTransaction;
    //getters ... setters
}
```

Stack trace followed like this, Let me know

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.<init>(JsonWriter.java:190)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeWriter.<init>(JsonTreeWriter.java:58)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:478)
at com.google.gson.Gson$3.serialize(Gson.java:140)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:129)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:1)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:70)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:479)
at com.google.gson.Gson$3.serialize(Gson.java:140)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:129)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:1)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:70)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:479)
at com.google.gson.Gson$3.serialize(Gson.java:140)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:129)
at com.nextenders.common.ControlTransactionSerializer.serialize(ControlTransactionJsonUtil.java:1)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:70)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:479)
at com.google.gson.Gson$3.serialize(Gson.java:140)
```

Here is my `serializer` and `deserializer`

```
class ControlTransactionDeserializer implements
        JsonDeserializer<ControlTransaction> {
    @Override
    public ControlTransaction deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json, type);
    }
}

class ControlTransactionSerializer implements
        JsonSerializer<ControlTransaction> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ControlTransaction ctr, Type type,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(ctr, type);
    }
}
```

Whats going on in backend. I just passed a empty Object, that means new `ControlTransaction()`, Still unable to parse.

Comment: Let's see your serializer.

Comment: Did you check if referenceGridTransaction is referring to crt?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added the serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a `JsonSerializer` is to serialize the fields of an Object, not the object itself. However, you are passing the object you've already told `Gson` to serialize. The following

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(ControlTransaction ctr, Type type,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return context.serialize(ctr, type);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(ControlTransaction ctr, Type type,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
            ControlTransaction.class,
              new ControlTransactionSerializer()).create().toJsonTree(ctr);
}
```

which I hope you can see is going into recursive loop.

The `JsonSerializationContext` is basically the underlying structure that the `Gson` object uses to serialize your object. When it sees your type `ControlTransaction`, it will delegate to your custom `JsonSerializer`. But your `JsonSerializer` will send it back to the `JsonSerializationContext` and the loop goes on.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to the issue. What you suggest is won't compile. If possible please check the class `JsonDeserializer` http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html and an example also there.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I wasn't being careful (or trying to make it compile). It's just to give you an idea that the `JsonSerializationContext` is basically the underlying structure that the `Gson` object uses to serialize your object. When it sees your type `ControlTransaction`, it will delegate to your custom `JsonSerializer`. But your `JsonSerializer` will send it back to the `JsonSerializationContext` and the loop goes on.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050869/how-to-invoke-another-serializer-from-a-custom-gson-jsonserializer) an example of custom serialization.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Your start of day, my end of day :) You're welcome. Good morning!

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. Good night :) Your brains are still active even at end of the day.